# Firebase : How to validate a User ID posted by another user.

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm trying to create a group chat.

1. A user creates a group.
2. Adds users to that group, by UserID, which were created during the firebase signup.

** How do I check first before storing these User Ids under a certain group node that the user IDs are valid?**

If there's another method I can use please advise.

Comment: You can create an index of valid UIDs. That way you can query your firebase using something like: `/users-index/98a6ec42-20ec-48d6-9937-e0c5742eabed`; if it exists proceed with storing the userid in the relevant group node.

Comment: @Gregg can you give an example of how I'd query these on the firebase server with validating rules? Please write as an answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a /users node, each user would be listed in the node under their uid:

```
users
   uid_0
     name: Henry Winkler
     email: henry@thefonz.com
```

A /users node is a typical design pattern in Firebase and a user child node is generally added at the same time their Firebase account is created. You can store anything you want about the user so it makes it one-stop-shopping for your user data.

Comment: Maybe I failed mentioning that I want to validate this on the firebase server. With database rules.

Comment: @Relm User id's are created by the Firebase server and therefore are always valid. The only instance is if the the user was removed from Firebase - in that case however, you would also remove them from the /users node. Maybe I don't understand the comment?

Comment: They are valid yes, and if they are from the user they could be anything. I want to check them again, on the server.

Comment: @Relm uid's are created by the Firebase server when the user is created and are part of the auth.uid. They are not from the user, they are from the auth.uid only. The auth.uid cannot be changed and as long as the user doesn't have remove access from the /users node, they will always be valid as well.

Comment: Maybe my questions isn't clear. The user IDs are sent to the user's device when they are browsing users to chat with, and to add a user to a chat group, I have to send the IDs they've chosen back to the server to create a group with those IDs, so I want to first validate the IDs.

Comment: @Relm It's not clear why they need to be validated. If the uid's were auth.uid, they would always be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Jay mentioned you'll need a structure such as:

```
users
   $uid
      ...
```

I haven't been able to find any way to solve this problem without such a structure, so I had to create one just for this purpose. I handled such creation using an [`onCreate` Firebase function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-functions#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation) where I simply set some dummy data (`"active": true`) for each new user.

With that structure in place you can now check for it in `.read`/`.write`/`.validate` rules:

```
"groups": {
    "$group": {
        "members": {
            "$uid": {
                ".validate": "root.child('users/' + $uid).exists()"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I haven't verified that exact code just yet...